# Generate PDF based on Particular Div id in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Is there a way to generate pdf in rails based on div id.

```
Sample code:
<div id="pdf_download">
   <h1>Hello Welcome to PDF
</div>

<div id="seconf_pdf">
 <h2>Second PDF</h2>
</div>
```

Now i want to download only the div id "pdf_download" as pdf, Is it possible? Can anyone explain how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a gem that does that - [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf). Internally it seems to depend on `wkhtmltopdf`, so you should be able to install this on your production environment.